# @Input() is undefined even though it is

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working on a project that shows movie information. Using @Input(), I am binding the movie details from the parent component (movies) to the child component (movie-detail).

Parent Component (Movie)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IMovie } from './movie';
import { MoviesService } from './movies.service';
import { IPopular } from './popular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MovieDetailComponent } from '../movie-detail/movie-detail.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies',
  templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies.component.css']
})
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  moviesList: IPopular[] = [];
  movie: IMovie;
  selectedMovie: IMovie;

  constructor(private _moviesService: MoviesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._moviesService.getPopularMovies()
      .subscribe(moviesList => {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
      },
        error => console.log(error)
      );

  }

  onSelect(movie: IMovie): void {
    this.selectedMovie = movie;
    window.setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, 5000); }, 300);
  }
}
```

Parent HTML

```
<div>
  <ul class="movies" *ngFor="let movie of moviesList.results">
    <li [class.selected]="movie === selectedMovie" (click)="onSelect(movie)">
      <img class="poster" [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/'+ movie.poster_path">
      <br> {{movie.title}} 
    </li> 
  </ul>
</div>

<app-movie-detail [movie]='selectedMovie'></app-movie-detail>
```

IMovie

```
export interface IMovie {
    vote_count: number;
    id: number;
    video: boolean;
    vote_average: number;
    title: string;
    popularity: number;
    poster_path: string;
    original_language: string;
    original_title: string;
    genre_ids: number[];
    backdrop_path: string;
    adult: boolean;
    overview: string;
    release_date: string;
}
```

IPopular

```
 import { IMovie } from './movie';

export interface IPopular {
    results: Array<IMovie>;
    page: number;
    total_results: number;
    dates: DateTimeFormat;
    total_pages: number;
}
```

Child Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { IResult } from './result';
import { IVideo } from './video';
import { IMovie } from '../movies/movie';
import { MovieDetailService } from './movie-detail.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-detail',
  templateUrl: './movie-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-detail.component.css']
})
export class MovieDetailComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() movie: IMovie;

  videoList: IVideo[] = [];
  video: IResult;

  constructor(private _moviedetailService: MovieDetailService) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this._moviedetailService.getTrailer(this.movie.id)
      .subscribe(videoList => {
        this.videoList = videoList;
      },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  ScrollToTop(): void {
    window.setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(5000, 0); }, 300);
  }
}
```

Child HTML

```
<body class="background" [background]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original'+ movie.backdrop_path" *ngIf="movie">
  <div class="detailpage">
    <h1>{{ movie.title }}</h1>
    <div>
      <img class="poster" [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/'+ movie.poster_path">
      <div class="movieinfo">
        <h2>Overview:</h2>
        <p>{{ movie.overview }}</p>
        <h3>Rating:</h3>
        <p>{{ movie.vote_average}} / 10</p>
        <h3>Release Date:</h3>
        <p>{{movie.release_date}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="trailer" *ngFor="let videos of videoList.video">
        <iframe [src]="'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videos.key"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="top" (click)="ScrollToTop()">Back to top</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

IVideo

```
import { IResult } from './result';

export interface IVideo {
  id: number;
  results: Array<IResult>;
}
```

IResult

```
export interface IResult {
    id: string;
    iso_639_1: string;
    iso_3166_1: string;
    key: string;
    name: string;
    site: string;
    size: number;
    type: string;
}
```

Using this codes, I am getting a ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at MovieDetailComponent.ngOnChanges (movie-detail.component.ts:22)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12365)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SearchresultComponent.html:10)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14655)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13802)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
```

What do you guys recommend to fix this issue?

Comment: You should check for `if(this.movie)` at `ngOnChanges` because first time bound will trigger this. This is the sequence for component lifecycle hooks https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence

Comment: @MiguelLattuada adding  `if(this.movie)` at `ngOnChanges` does not trigger the `getTrailer(this.movie.id)` code. Does this mean movie is undefined?

Comment: Yes, you´re setting [movie]=selectedMovie which is undefined until you call `onSelect` (clicking the li), after that your code will work correctly...

Comment: The problem is even after I clicked on the li, I am still getting an error that `this.movie.id` is still undefined. In the Child HTML code, `{{movie.title}}` is defined and works accordingly. However, in the Child component, in `ngOnchanges`, `this.movie.id` is undefined.

Comment: You should put the validation, otherwise your app will remain broken. Check haifzhan answer

Comment: @MiguelLattuada adding `if(this.movie) does work! I just checked the console and found out that it is running the code and getting the data from the api. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It most likely is because your `selectedMovie` is `undefined` until you click on one. You can solve it be hiding your movie details component if one is not selected:

```
<app-movie-detail *ngIf="selectedMovie" [movie]="selectedMovie"></app-movie-detail>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have tried the solution you suggested, however, it does not work. When I select a movie, all the information in movie detail is shown, however, the console is giving me error because "this.movie.id" is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property values.
>   Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.

Wrap your code into a condition check: `if(this.movie) {...}`

```
ngOnChanges() {
  if(this.movie) {
    console.log(this.movie.id)
  }
}
```

`ngOnChanges()` will be invoked again when input properties changes.

Comment: @DevonSugianto Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

When the child component is initiated `this.movie` information is not available. Coz as per your logic movie, details are only available when a movie selected in parent component. Hence the undefined error.

Service call in `ngOnChanges` should be made only when movie details are available. Try updating `ngOnChanges` from the child component like this

```
ngOnChanges() {
if (this.movie) {
 this._moviedetailService.getTrailer(this.movie.id)
  .subscribe(videoList => {
    this.videoList = videoList;
  },
    error => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

}